# Binding a dynamic list to a column of ComboBoxes in a DataGrid only works until actually showing the list

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm working on a WPF application according to the MVVM pattern and am facing a challenge that I abstracted in the code below.
The app contains a DataGrid with 2 ComboBox columns (each generated in a different manner). The aim is to have a ComboBox present only those items that have not yet been selected by the other ComboBoxes in the same column.

The comboboxes are Bound to an ObservableCollection of Professions. Each profession has a Boolean "Selectable", and a ComboBox should only show those entries with a value of "true".

The list contains:

- Painter
- Poet
- Scientist

To simulate an interactive Command from XAML to the ViewModel, I placed a button that will set the Scientist to Selectable to "false".

App.xaml:

```
<Application x:Class="wpf_ComboBoxColumn.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
</Application>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
using System.Windows;

namespace wpf_ComboBoxColumn
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = new MainViewModel();
        }
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="wpf_ComboBoxColumn.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:wpf_ComboBoxColumn"
        xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:wpf_ComboBoxColumn"
        Title="Combobox Column Binding" Height="350" Width="460">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ComboBox}}">
                <Setter Property="ItemsSource"
                        Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" />
                <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ComboBoxItem}}">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Selectable}" Value="False">
                                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                                </DataTrigger>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Selectable}" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.DataContext>
            <viewModel:MainViewModel />
        </Grid.DataContext>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding People}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" />
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn
                    Header="ComboBoxColumn"
                    SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Description, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
                    SelectedValuePath="Description"
                    DisplayMemberPath="Description"
                    >
                    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.Professions}"/>
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.Professions}"/>
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="TemplateColumn">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ComboBox 
                                ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.Professions, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"
                                DisplayMemberPath="Description"
                                SelectedValue="{Binding Profession, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                >
                            </ComboBox>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
        <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="210,290,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Command="{Binding DebugCommand}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

CustomCommand.cs (ICommand implementation):

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace wpf_ComboBoxColumn
{
    public class CustomCommand: ICommand
    {
        private readonly Action<object> execute;

        public CustomCommand(Action<object> execute)
        {
            this.execute = execute;
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            execute(parameter);
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add => CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
            remove => CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
        }
    }
}
```

MainViewModel.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace wpf_ComboBoxColumn
{
    public class NotifyUIBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public class Profession
    {
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public Boolean Selectable { get; set; }
    }

    public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Profession { get; set; }
    }

    public class MainViewModel : NotifyUIBase
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Person> People { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<Profession> Professions { get; set; }
        public ICommand DebugCommand { get; set; }

        public MainViewModel()
        {
            DebugCommand = new CustomCommand(Debug);

            People = new ObservableCollection<Person>
            {
                new Person{Name="Tom", Profession="" },
                new Person{Name= "Dick", Profession="" },
                new Person{Name= "Harry", Profession="" }
            };

            Professions = new ObservableCollection<Profession>
            {
                new Profession{ Description="Painter", Selectable=true},
                new Profession{ Description="Poet", Selectable=true},
                new Profession{ Description="Scientist", Selectable=true},
            };
        }

        private void Debug(object obj)
        {
            Professions[2].Selectable = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Now consider the following scenario (I'm still trying to figure out how to include screen shots):

- Open the app: This will show a grid with 3 columns:
  First column shows the names "Tom", "Dick" and "Harry".
  Second column contains a ComboBox for each person. It requires multiple clicks to open.
  Third column also contains a ComboBox for each person. This one is recognizable as such.
- Choose "Scientist" for Tom
- Click the button (to fake that we executed code that changed Profession.Selectable)
- Click on the Combobox for Dick
- This will indeed show the remaining Professions (without Scientist), for the rightmost column of ComboBoxes. The leftmost column will still show all options, so this one fails right away.
- Click on the Combobox for Tom again
- This will, even for the rightmost column of ComboBoxes, show all options again (or rather: still)!

It turns out that the list, once shown, is not dynamically updated. Until we click on it, it is (makes me think of Quantum Mechanics, but that's another story)

The question is: Is there a way to force a refresh of the ItemsSource? Preferrably, of course, respecting MVVM, but at this point, I'll go for any working solution, using either ComboBox-type.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried raising the `PropertyChanged` event on the `Selectable` property? You're binding to it, and then you're changing it, so if you want the view to change based on this property, it needs to raise `PropertyChanged`.

Comment: I can't believe it was that simple. In my original application I moved this property to a class of its own and although the viewmodel had the PropertyChanged call on all of its properties, I complete failed to do it on Selectable in the new class. Luckily I used this as a template for the posted code, so it had the same error. Thanks for your quick reply!

Now I am facing the challenge of accepting your answer, there is supposed to be something to be a check mark, but I can't find it

Comment: That's a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: For me it was an answer, despite the simplicity :-). 
Perhaps redcurry can make it an answer

Comment: @Falcon451 I turned my comment into an answer. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to raise the `PropertyChanged` event on the `Selectable` property. You're binding to it, and then you're changing it, so if you want the view to change based on this property, it needs to raise `PropertyChanged`.